# How to print dates and item prices in Arabic numerals in NetSuite advance pdf template?

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, advanced-custom-fields, suitescript

How to print dates and item prices in Arabic numerals in NetSuite advance pdf template? for specific reason I need to show Arabic numerals in invoice. how can I convert them on runtime? image is attached for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT9CL.gif)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see the updated shorter answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a converter like this in javascript

```js
var ArabicNumbers = ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"]

function arabify(num) {
  num = num + ""
  let newNum = ""

  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    newNum += ArabicNumbers[num[i]]
  }
  return newNum
}

console.log(arabify(94569))
console.log(arabify(100))
console.log(arabify(256))
```

when you have a number that has to be shown in Arabic numbers, you can just run this function for your number in javascript. 
I don't have experience with netsuite, so I can't help you about this( 
but you tagged js too, so I thought you may want to see a way to convert it in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I shorter one-line method to convert numbers to Arabic and keeping all text unchanged is as follows:

```
const numToAr=n=>(""+n).replace(/\d/g,d=>"٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"[d]);
```

Here are a few examples:

```js
const numToAr=n=>(""+n).replace(/\d/g,d=>"٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"[d]);

console.log(numToAr(94569))
console.log(numToAr(100))
console.log(numToAr(256))
console.log(numToAr("العدد هو 543"))
```